# Is there any way to make this "GetPropertyName" function faster?

Tags: c#, reflection, c#-4.0, expression

Currently I'm using an Expression Tree to get the name of a property.

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T, TReturn>(Expression<Func<T, TReturn>> expression)
{
     MemberExpression body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
     return body.Member.Name;
}
```

I saw somewhere where they used the string version (expression.toString()) of the expression to cache it in a dictionary and then get the property name the second time from the cache.

Does that actually help or is there a better way?

Comment: Because you've profiled this particular method in your application and found it to be the performance bottleneck?  Database calls will trump 1000 instances of reflection in profiling.  Measure, measure, measure, then optimize.

Comment: I know measure before you optimize. But since it had to do with reflection I figured I'd ask.

Comment: Is it slow? I've found that reflection is slow when measured against direct class access, but not slow in a real-world usual sense. Yes, caching the value can be faster. I agree with @mellamokb. Have you ever read Jeff Atwood's Micro-Optimization theater blog post. Its a good read, http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html

Comment: Replacing `string s = GetPropertyName<...>(x => x.Foo)` with `string s = "Foo"` should make it faster... not very helpful, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Reflection: Dodge Common Performance Pitfalls to Craft Speedy Applications

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163759.aspx

**Fast & light reflection functions**

- typeof
- Object.GetType
- typeof == Object.GetType
- Type equivalence APIs (including typehandle operator overloads)
- get_Module
- get_MemberType
- Some of the IsXX predicate APIs
- New token/handle resolution APIs in the .NET Framework 2.0

**Costly reflection functions**

- GetXX  APIs (MethodInfo, PropertyInfo, FieldInfo, and so on)
- GetCustomAttributes
- Type.InvokeMember
- Invoke APIs (MethodInfo.Invoke, FieldInfo.GetValue, and so on)
- get_Name (Name property)
- Activator.CreateInstance

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by "does that help".

The idea behind such caching is that it will be faster than inspecting the expression. My first reaction to that is "that will probably be even slower", but 99% of the time such intuitive guesses are wrong, so let's just ignore that for the time being.

Caching is a tradeoff. You will be introducing memory overhead (for the dictionary), plus the runtime costs of creating the dictionary, in the *hopes* that the `ToString` plus dictionary lookup operation will be faster enough than inspecting the expression to be worth the costs (plus the increased complexity). Even if that is true, a faster lookup will not matter **at all** unless you are doing that in a big loop somewhere. Is that true in your case? If not, you should not bother.

Now, if you were writing a general-purpose library, you wouldn't know how *the users* of that library choose to utilize it. Maybe some of them would indeed make such calls in a loop. In this case, it might be a good idea to cover your back and try caching; *but it would still be a bad decision to implement caching for a not-likely scenario if it makes your more-likely scenario worse*.

And of course, judging if caching would be for the better or for worse should always be done by *measuring*.

Comment: I'm using this with all my models to do searches. So I won't be using this in a loop but calling it often.

Comment: @Donny: "Often" doesn't sound like enough. But that's not the point: measure! :)

Comment: Anyone else want to sound smart and tell me to measure?